# How to display data in a Dynamic Pane?

Tags: dynamic

How to display data in a Dynamic Pane
without exponents?

Some data:

```
data = Range[1, 1000];
```

Slider data has to be added to data:

```
Slider[Dynamic[n], {0, 10000000}]
```

A Dynamic Pane:

```
Dynamic[Pane[Pane[TableForm[n + data],100], ImageSize -> {200, 200}, Scrollbars -> True]]
```

Plane numbers without exponents are wanted in the Pane.
  .

**UPDATE**

Build a file with 10.000 records.
(File could have an arbitrary number of records)
Make each record a string 50 bytes in length.
The content of the records does not matter.

The method gives a Slider and a Pane.
The Slider allows to pre-set to a rough record position
in file. It sticks always to a record boundary.
The Panes Scrollbars allow to see through the
chunk of records loaded into the pane.

The Question is:
How to modify the working of Module[] so its functionality is
preserved and the display of the StreamPosition value avoided.

This value is visible right above the Slider object.
Only the Slider, the Pane and the Panes
content should be visible.

```
(* txt data file 10.000 fixed length records 50 bytes each *)  
infil = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test 10T fixed.txt";  

(* a stream onto the file *)  
str = OpenRead[infil, BinaryFormat -> True];  

(* a table to build up the shown record numbers *)  
panebias = Range[1, 200];  

(* a table with a delimiter sign to separate the Pane panels   
first and second column *)  
deli = Table["|", {200}];  

(* the last StreamPointerPosition to go to fit the last record  
into the pane. 10.000 records times records bytes plus 2 bytes  
for taking into account BinaryFormat *)  
last = 10000*52 - 200*52;  

(* preset the Slider position for its StreamPosition *)  
n = 0;  

Module[{},
 Column[
  {Dynamic[SetStreamPosition[str, n]],
   Slider[Dynamic[n], {0, last, 52}, ImageSize -> 450, 
    Appearance -> Small],
   Pane[Grid /@ 
     Dynamic[Transpose[{n/52 + panebias, deli, 
        ReadList[str, Record, 200]}]],
    ImageSize -> {450, 200}, Scrollbars -> True]}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
data = Range[1, 100];
Column[{
  Slider[Dynamic[n], {0, 10000000, 1}],
  Pane[
   TableForm /@ Dynamic[n + data],
   ImageSize -> {200, 200},
  Scrollbars -> True]}]
```

[image: solution 1]

*Update*

Perhaps this is what you're seeking:

```
data = Range[1, 1000];
Row[{
  Column[
   {Slider[Dynamic[m], {0, 10000000, 1}],
    Pane[TableForm /@ Dynamic[m + data], ImageSize -> {200, 200}, 
     Scrollbars -> True]
    }],
  Spacer[100],
  Column[
   {Slider[Dynamic[n], {0, 10000000, 1}],
    Pane[TableForm /@ Dynamic[n + data], ImageSize -> {200, 200}, 
     Scrollbars -> True]
    }]}]
```

[image: more sliders]

*Another update*

You can have scrolling panes inside scrolling panes.

```
Pane[
 Row[{
   Column[{
    Slider[Dynamic[m], {0, 10000000, 1}], 
     Pane[TableForm /@ Dynamic[m + data], ImageSize -> {200, 200}, 
      Scrollbars -> True]}], Spacer[100], 
   Column[{
    Slider[Dynamic[n], {0, 10000000, 1}], 
     Pane[TableForm /@ Dynamic[n + data], ImageSize -> {200, 200}, 
      Scrollbars -> True]}]}],
 Scrollbars -> True]
```

[image: scrolling pane madness]

But this question is getting paneful...

Comment: Yes.  .  .Thats the point.  .  .How can you place one more column inside the pane?.  .  .To the right of the data column   already existing.

Comment: @HpRadojewskiSchäferVon Oh, I thought you wanted to get rid of the exponents...

Comment: That's rigth.  .  .I like your solution.  .  .In addition to this I want more then one column inside the pane.  .  .From a different source, say from another Range.

Comment: @HpRadojewskiSchäferVon Like that?

Comment: No.  .  .A second column should be inside one and the same  Pane.  .  .Data from a second source.  .  A List or Range.  .   Or if you asked me what i am trying to do, actually the second source will be a Read form an external file. Displaying the records of that file chunk after chunk.

Comment: [Nice score!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EM86d.png)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you for capturing it! I will stay up all night to see if I can capture your fleeting "66,666" score... :)

Comment: I actually managed to capture [55,555](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FnRzt.png) but [I like yours better.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8907800#8907800)  "One point twenty-one gigawatts!"  For sixes I'll never match [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/j8vPn.png).

Comment: I put the peaces together.  .  .See my update for a question.

Comment: Thanks for a lot of useful suggestions.   .   .I could integrate them and solve the task.

Comment: Five+ years have gone by with no comment about the truly awful pun in this answer.  I have remedied the situation.